# Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, optimization, cpu-cache

Below are two programs that are almost identical except that I switched the `i` and `j` variables around. They both run in different amounts of time. Could someone explain why this happens?

Version 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main () {
  int i,j;
  static int x[4000][4000];
  for (i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) {
      x[j][i] = i + j; }
  }
}
```

Version 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main () {
  int i,j;
  static int x[4000][4000];
  for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) {
     for (i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
       x[j][i] = i + j; }
   }
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange#The_utility_of_loop_interchange

Comment: Can you add some benchmark results?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888154/which-of-these-two-for-loops-is-more-efficient-in-terms-of-time-and-cache-perfor

Comment: @naught101 The benchmarks will show a performance difference of anywhere between 3 to 10 times. This is basic C/C++, I'm completely stumped as to how this got so many votes...

Comment: i think this issue is related to loading array page to memory by OS paging policy

Comment: I think the question could be not only for c.

Comment: @TC1: I don't think it's that basic; maybe intermediate. But it should be no surprise that the "basic" stuff tends to be useful to more people, hence the many upvotes. Moreover, this is a question that's hard to google, even if it is "basic".

Comment: I added this test as javascript to http://jsperf.com/2-dimensional-array-loops and you can check the effect there

Comment: @LarsH I never said it's basic in general, I said it's basic C/C++. Those languages are already quite advanced all by themselves. "Tricks and sorcery" like this comes with them as a given, and anyone making use of them should familiarize themselves beforehand. There's a couple more, off the top of my hand, using postfix incrementors instead of prefix on STL iterators to prevent making an unnecessary copy, but I take it you get the gist. They give you all the rope you need to hang yourself and no signs that you're about to, most other (higher level) languages don't let you do that.

Comment: @TC1: basic C is what I was referring to (this issue isn't specific to C++, which is a huge leap up in complexity). But this same problem can apply to BASIC. "Anyone making use of them should familiarize themselves beforehand" - easy for a knowledgeable person to say. Did you learn about this particular problem before you made your first nested loop with a 2D array? I know I sure didn't! I don't think I used such large arrays, but it wasn't because I knew to stay away from them for performance reasons!

Comment: Can be different for gpu kernels than cpu.

Comment: I'm re-opening this question since I believe it is a better "canonical duplicate" than the one linked, mainly because of some nice answers posted here.

Comment: @naught101 **Benchmark results** for N=10000: the first method is 3.68 times slower, 1.092s vs 0.296s. (Results from one run, there is quite a lot of variability between runs). The speed difference will probably depend on the relative size between your CPU's cache and the size of the array chosen.

Comment: GCC 8 and upcoming Clang 7 (with `-mllvm -enable-loopinterchange` flag) have improved their loop interchange optimization routines and generate the exact same assembly for both cases https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EB-PRg

Answer (score 643, accepted):

As others have said, the issue is the store to the memory location in the array: `x[i][j]`. Here's a bit of insight why:

You have a 2-dimensional array, but memory in the computer is inherently 1-dimensional. So while you imagine your array like this:

```
0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3
----+-----+-----+----
1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3
----+-----+-----+----
2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3
```

Your computer stores it in memory as a single line:

```
0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3 | 1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3
```

In the 2nd example, you access the array by looping over the 2nd number first, i.e.:

```
x[0][0] 
        x[0][1]
                x[0][2]
                        x[0][3]
                                x[1][0] etc...
```

Meaning that you're hitting them all in order. Now look at the 1st version. You're doing:

```
x[0][0]
                                x[1][0]
                                                                x[2][0]
        x[0][1]
                                        x[1][1] etc...
```

Because of the way C laid out the 2-d array in memory, you're asking it to jump all over the place. But now for the kicker: Why does this matter? All memory accesses are the same, right?

No: because of caches. Data from your memory gets brought over to the CPU in little chunks (called 'cache lines'), typically 64 bytes. If you have 4-byte integers, that means you're geting 16 consecutive integers in a neat little bundle. It's actually fairly slow to fetch these chunks of memory; your CPU can do a lot of work in the time it takes for a single cache line to load.

Now look back at the order of accesses: The second example is (1) grabbing a chunk of 16 ints, (2) modifying all of them, (3) repeat 4000*4000/16 times. That's nice and fast, and the CPU always has something to work on.

The first example is (1) grab a chunk of 16 ints, (2) modify only one of them, (3) repeat 4000*4000 times. That's going to require 16 times the number of "fetches" from memory. Your CPU will actually have to spend time sitting around waiting for that memory to show up, and while it's sitting around you're wasting valuable time.

**Important Note:**

Now that you have the answer, here's an interesting note: there's no inherent reason that your second example has to be the fast one. For instance, in Fortran, the first example would be fast and the second one slow. That's because instead of expanding things out into conceptual "rows" like C does, Fortran expands into "columns", i.e.:

```
0,0 | 1,0 | 2,0 | 0,1 | 1,1 | 2,1 | 0,2 | 1,2 | 2,2 | 0,3 | 1,3 | 2,3
```

The layout of C is called 'row-major' and Fortran's is called 'column-major'. As you can see, it's very important to know whether your programming language is row-major or column-major! Here's a link for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: You have the "first" and "second" versions around the wrong way; the first example varies the *first* index in the inner loop, and will be the slower executing example.

Comment: Great answer. If Mark wants read more about such nitty gritty, I'd recommend a book like Write Great Code.

Comment: Bonus points for pointing out that C changed the row order from Fortran. For scientific computing L2 cache size is everything because if all your arrays fit into L2 then computation can be completed without going to main memory.

Comment: @birryree: The freely-available [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) is also a good read.

Comment: Great answer but I actually imagine array as 0,0 1,0 2,0.. Why wouls you say 0,0 1,0 2,0 ?

Comment: @KorayTugay There's no logic to it one way or the other: either one is just as good. C just arbitrarily chose row-major (ie 0,0, 0,1, 0,2, etc) and that means you're stuck with it if you use a row-major language.... which is just about every language these days!

Comment: @RobertMartin It's not an arbitrary choice for C. In C multi-dimensional arrays don't exist. It's an array of arrays instead, which makes it automatically row-major.

Comment: @RobertMartin you are discussing native languages like C,C++, can this be repeated in other languages like Java, JavaScript, does JVM or Java compiler/optimizer process such concerns for us?

Answer (score 73):

Nothing to do with assembly.  This is due to [cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_miss#Cache_miss).

C multidimensional arrays are stored with the last dimension as the fastest.  So the first version will miss the cache on every iteration, whereas the second version won't.  So the second version should be substantially faster.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange.

Answer (score 24):

Version 2 will run much faster because it uses your computer's cache better than version 1. If you think about it, arrays are just contiguous areas of memory. When you request an element in an array, your OS will probably bring in a memory page into cache that contains that element. However, since the next few elements are also on that page (because they are contiguous), the next access will already be in cache! This is what version 2 is doing to get it's speed up.

Version 1, on the other hand, is accessing elements column wise, and not row wise. This sort of access is not contiguous at the memory level, so the program cannot take advantage of the OS caching as much.

Comment: With these array sizes, probably the cache manager in the CPU rather than in the OS is responsible here.

Answer (score 13):

The reason is cache-local data access.  In the second program you're scanning linearly through memory which benefits from caching and prefetching.  Your first program's memory usage pattern is far more spread out and therefore has worse cache behavior.

Answer (score 11):

Besides the other excellent answers on cache hits, there is also a possible optimization difference. Your second loop is likely to be optimized by the compiler into something equivalent to:

```
for (j=0; j<4000; j++) {
  int *p = x[j];
  for (i=0; i<4000; i++) {
    *p++ = i+j;
  }
}
```

This is less likely for the first loop, because it would need to increment the pointer "p" with 4000 each time.

**EDIT:** `p++` and even `*p++ = ..` can be compiled to a single CPU instruction in most CPU's. `*p = ..; p += 4000` cannot, so there is less benefit in optimising it. It's also more difficult, because the compiler needs to know and use the size of the inner array. And it does not occur that often in the inner loop in normal code (it occurs only for multidimensional arrays, where the last index is kept constant in the loop, and the second to last one is stepped), so optimisation is less of a priority.

Comment: I don't get what 'because it would need to jump the pointer "p" with 4000 each time' means.

Comment: @Veedrac The pointer would need to be incremented with 4000 inside the inner loop: `p += 4000` i.s.o. `p++`

Comment: Why would the compiler find that a problem? `i` is already incremented by a non-unit value, given it's a pointer increment.

Comment: I've added  more explanation

Comment: Try typing `int *f(int *p) {
    *p++ = 10;
    return p;
}

int *g(int *p) {
    *p = 10;
    p += 4000;
    return p;
}` into https://gcc.godbolt.org/. The two seem to compile basically the same.

Comment: Select e.g. ARM gcc 4.8.2 as compiler, and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 9):

This line the culprit :

```
x[j][i]=i+j;
```

The second version uses continuous memory thus will be substantially faster.

I tried with

```
x[50000][50000];
```

and the time of execution is 13s for version1 versus 0.6s for version2.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>I try to give a generic answer.</sub>

Because `i[y][x]` is a shorthand for `*(i + y*array_width + x)` in C (try out the classy `int P[3]; 0[P] = 0xBEEF;`).

As you iterate over `y`, you iterate over chunks of size `array_width * sizeof(array_element)`. If you have that in your inner loop, then you will have `array_width * array_height` iterations over those chunks.

By flipping the order, you will have only `array_height` chunk-iterations, and between any chunk-iteration, you will have `array_width` iterations of only `sizeof(array_element)`.

While on really old x86-CPUs this did not matter much, nowadays' x86 do a lot of prefetching and caching of data. You probably produce many [cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_misses#Operation) in your slower iteration-order.