# Why does changing for loop iteration order increase the runtime?

Tags: c++, c, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra)

I have this simple for loops

```
for (i=0;i<10000;i++){
   for(j=0;j<10000;j++){
      a[i][j]=i+j;
      }}
```

when I change the order of these for loops to:

```
for (j=0;j<10000;j++){
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
      a[i][j]=i+j;
      }}
```

I see that the runtime increases dramatically. Why this happen?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss of locality of access causes more page faults.