# 2D arrays of objects in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How do I set up an 2d array (array of arrays in java)?

```
    dmap = new sq[255][255];
    for (int y = 0; y < 255; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < 255; ++x)
            dmap[x][y] = new sq();
```

where `sq` is my other class doesn't work well- I get a long hang (2 mins) and no logging or printfs appear in Eclipse debug views (console + log).

Comment: Unless `new sq()` hangs, there's no problem in your code.

Comment: The only possible issue is that this should be `[y][x]` instead of `[x][y]` in the inner loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra.

Answer (score 1):

At first You must initialize first dimension of array and then go to next, here is the right code:

```
sq dmap[][] = new sq[256][];
for (int x = 0; x < 255; ++x){
   dmap[x] = new sq[256];
   for(int y = 0 ; y < 255 ; ++y){
      dmap[x][y] = new sq();
   }
}
```