# Performance conflicts for Loop interchange

Tags: c++, performance, caching, loops

```
#include <windows.h>

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}

int main()
{
    StartCounter();
int i,j;
    static int x[4000][4000];
#if 1 //Version 1
    for (i = 0; i < 4000; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) 
        {
            x[j][i] = i + j; 
        }
    }
#else //Version 2
    for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4000; i++) 
        {
            x[j][i] = i + j; 
        }
    }
#endif    
    cout << GetCounter() <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the above code in VS2012 on Win7-32bit machine.

The execution time for Version-1 is 0.200 seconds and for Version-2 is 0.071 seconds.

Arrays are just contiguous areas of memory and C++ stores arrays in Row major fashion. When you request an element in an array, your OS will probably bring in a memory page into cache that contains that element. However, since the next few elements are also on that page (because they are contiguous), the next access will already be in cache for **Version-1** !

So, the Version-1 has to be fast.

But result shows that version-2 is fast.

Please explain why the results conflict.

Comment: I think you're confused - version 2 will be accessed in row major order, i.e. sequential/contiguous addressing, so it will be faster. The confusion probably comes form the fact that you have your array indices reversed, i.e. `x[j][i]` instead of `x[i][j]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the order of the loops affect performance when iterating over a 2D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra)

Comment: @PaulR: Thanks for your quick reply. Silly me. I used x[j][i] instead of x[i][j] and it confused me..Really thanks.