# Buffer size correlating directly to hash calculation speed

Tags: c, hash, openssl, buffer

I've created a function which hashes a file (~2GB) and outputs it into a another file, however buffer size appears to correlate directly with the speed at which this is calculated. When the buffer set to `[1024]` it is noticeably slower than when it is set to `[1048576]` for example.

Increasing the buffer beyond `[1048576]` slows this down however, and I wondered why this was so?

It appears that 1MB is the ideal size, I'm just not sure why!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe that's the size of your cache in your system?

Comment: This previous question (and its links to other SO questions) "[how the cache size and array size affect the performance of mathematical operations on an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083642/how-the-cache-size-and-array-size-affect-the-performance-of-mathematical-operati)" may be useful.