# Why is there such a big execution time difference between these two implementation of multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I recently ran across a comment which is as follows:

> Multi-dimensional arrays take a lot of time for array access. To increase their caching and access speed, it is advised to keep the indices from smaller to larger i.e. declaring `rmq` array like `rmq[11][11][1002][1002]` rather than `rmq[1002][1002][11][11]`.

I tried a code to test the same. In Code 1:

```
int pre_compute[18][100001];    //global variable

int main(){
    /*some precomputations on pre_compute array 
    of the order of size of the array*/

    /*Run 10^8 queries on pre_compute array,
    O(1) per query.*/
}
```

Code 2:

```
int pre_compute[100001][18];    //global variable

int main(){
    /*exact same precomputations on pre_compute array as done in Code 1 
    of the order of size of the array*/

    /*Run 10^8 queries on pre_compute array,
    O(1) per query.*/
}
```

Both the codes are identical except for the distribution of the array. Still there was a big execution time difference between the two codes. The first code took an average of `0.40 secs` on my PC, whereas the other code took an average of `1.42 secs`.

What can be a possible reason for such a big execution time difference between two implementations of an array?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-cache-friendly-code , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The latter of those is pretty-much *exactly* the problem and the description of what is happening in the inconveniently omitted code that actually uses the declared arrays. Nice job.

Comment: Please ask such providing a [MCVE] next time, or post one here if you disagree the duplicate answers your question.

Comment: In addition, any performance related question should be accompanied with the command-line used to build the test, more explicitly, what optimizations were used to build the program.  Too many times these types of questions come up, and it is discovered that the poster is testing an unoptimized and / or "debug" build, making the results meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the difference between row-major and column-major ordered matrices.

The difference is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order):

> In row-major order, consecutive elements of the rows of the array are contiguous in memory; in column-major order, consecutive elements of the columns are contiguous.

C and C++ are row-major, so they can leverage caching of rows because of spacial locality. This explains the dramatic increase in speedup.

Technically, if you want to save a lot of time, it might be better to represent your multidimensional arrays as 1D arrays. :)

Comment: As Fortran is Column Major order, porting Fortran->C without dealing with the issue can cause performance issues.

Comment: @EvilTeach Yep - absolute nightmare.

Comment: Representing the multidimensional array as a 1d array won't really change anything or save any time if your access patterns are row major. Performance improvement would come if you changed your access pattern from column major to row-major OR you use column-major access and go with the 1d representation with indexing computations to effect column-major storage order.