# Set all values of a row and/or column in c++ to 1 or 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, memset

I have a problem which requires resetting all values in a column to 0 or 1. The code which i am using is normal naive approach to set values by iterating each time. Is there any faster implementation.

```
//Size of board n*n
i=0;
cin>>x>>y;x--;
if(query=="SetRow")
{
  while(i!=N){ board[i][x]=y;i++;}
}
else
{
  while(i!=N){ board[i][x]=y;i++;}
}
```

y can be 0 or 1

Comment: What constitutes a "column"?

Comment: Which is it? 0 or 1? How do you decide what to do? (0 or 1?)

Comment: link to the problem please

Comment: -1, question makes no sense, not does it show any effort.

Comment: The clarification makes a lot of sense. I hope no one will do the 5th close vote. This code can actually be optimized. (well it was closed, voting to reopen)

Comment: @amit: Assuming the tags are correct, I really doubt whatever problem he is solving requires setting all columns to 1 or 0 quickly. It is most likely a problem in the direction he chooses to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, other then iterating the columns there are few optimizations you might want to make:

1. **Iterating columns is less efficient then iterating rows** (about *4 slower) due to [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) performance. In columns iteration, you have a cache miss for each element - while in rows iteration you have cache miss for 1 out of 4 elements (usually, it depends on architecture and size of data, but usually a cache line fits 4 integers).

   Thus - **if you iterate columns more often then rows-  redesign it**, in order to iterate rows more often. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9888154/572670) discusses a similar issue.

   Also, after you do it - you can use `memset()` which I believe is better optimized for this task.

   (Note: Compilers might do that for you automatically in some cases)
2. You can **use lazy initialization**, there is actually `O(1)` algorithm to initialize an array with constant value, it is described with more details here: [initalize an array in constant time](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/). This comes at the cost of ~triple the amount of space, and more expansive seek later on.

The idea behind it (2) is to maintain additional stack (logically, implemented as array+ pointer to top) and array, the additional array will indicate when it was first initialized (a number from 0 to n) and the stack will indicate which elements were already modified.

When you access `array[i]`, if `stack[additionalArray[i]] == i && additionalArray[i] < top` the value of the array is `array[i]`. Otherwise - it is the "initialized" value.

When doing `array[i] = x`, if it was not initialized yet (as seen before), you should set `additionalArray[i] = stack[top]` and increase `top`.

This results in `O(1)` initialization, but as said it requires additional memory and each access is more expansive.

The same principles described by the article regarding initializing an array in `O(1)` can also be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is taken from running codechef long contest.... hail cheaters .. close this thread

Comment: the people who solved the problems also read it from somewhere some book, some tutorial.. OP is not copying somebody's code.