# For matrix operation, Why is "ikj" faster than "ijk"?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

For matrix operation...

## ijk-algorithm

```
public static int[][] ijkAlgorithm(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

## ikj-algorithm

```
public static int[][] ikjAlgorithm(int[][] A, int[][] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int[][] C = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

I know **ikj** is faster than **ijk**, but don't know why. Have any simple explanation? Thank you.

Comment: I may be wrong but I really think it's the same in your sample code.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936132/why-does-the-order-of-the-loops-affect-performance-when-iterating-over-a-2d-arra

Comment: I also thought that at first, but these information were found: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/aldente39/20130305/1362471983 (Sorry for non-English)

Comment: @CertaiN  I apologize, you were right.

Comment: I gave an explanation for it in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9888269/572670), and @BinyaminSharet have explained it visually in the same thread. (Voting to close as a dupe). To make things short - CACHE.

Comment: @micha Nice answer, but not so clear for my question. Somehow with `ikj-algorithm`, memory fragmentation gets smaller on matrix **multiplication**, right? I suppose this is caused by special calculation **only on multiplication**, not addition or subtraction.

Comment: **ijk** and **kji** are unbalanced, but **ikj** is balanced?

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the second snippet, the compiler can optimise

```
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
```

into something equivalent to

```
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        int temp = A[i][k];  
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] += temp * B[k][j];
        }
    }
```

but no such optimisation can be made in the first snippet.  So the second snippet requires fewer lookups into the arrays.